# subprocess результат в переменную

Tags: python

Вот валидный код:

```
ps = int(subprocess.check_output(['wc', '-l', '/home/kali/openssh.txt']).split()[0])
print(ps)
```

Такой:

```
cmd = int(subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '600', 'google.com']).split()[0])
print(cmd)
```

Ошибку выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cmd = int(subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '600', 'google.com']).split()[0])
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'PING'
```

Comment: Ну так и кладите результат в переменную. Зачем вы его через int пытаетесь превратить в число, если результат даже рядом не число.

Comment: wc -l считает строки, это действительно int, целое число, а ping - проверяет ответ сервера на запрос - это не число

Comment: Как записать в переменную вывод пинг? Такой код: "cm = str(subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '600', 'google.com']).split()[0])
print(cm)" Пишет: "b'PING'"